# R:Converting from Character to POSIXct loses hours and minutes

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

Good morning,

I'm trying to convert from character to POSIXct, but when I do, I lose the hours and minutes from the data.

hourlyData (dataframe)

```
    Login   Expo    EquityUSD   Period                    UnrealizedProfitUSD
1   252957  0.00    7.187185    2014-02-03 00:00:00.000     0.00000
2   252957  0.00    7.187772    2014-02-03 01:00:00.000     0.00000
3   252957  0.00    7.188198    2014-02-03 02:00:00.000     0.00000
4   252957  0.00    7.187825    2014-02-03 03:00:00.000     0.00000
5   252957  0.00    7.187079    2014-02-03 04:00:00.000     0.00000
6   252957  0.00    7.187079    2014-02-03 05:00:00.000     0.00000
7   252957  0.00    7.188731    2014-02-03 06:00:00.000     0.00000
8   252957  0.00    7.186279    2014-02-03 07:00:00.000     0.00000
9   252957  0.00    7.187185    2014-02-03 08:00:00.000     0.00000
```

when I type class(hourlyData$Period) I get `Character`. 
When I try and convert this column as such `hourlyData$Period = as.POSIXct(hourlyData$Period)`, however, I get the following output:
hourlyData

```
    Login   Expo    EquityUSD   Period       UnrealizedProfitUSD
1   252957  0.00    7.187185    2014-02-03   0.00000
2   252957  0.00    7.187772    2014-02-03   0.00000
3   252957  0.00    7.188198    2014-02-03   0.00000
4   252957  0.00    7.187825    2014-02-03   0.00000
5   252957  0.00    7.187079    2014-02-03   0.00000
6   252957  0.00    7.187079    2014-02-03   0.00000
7   252957  0.00    7.188731    2014-02-03   0.00000
8   252957  0.00    7.186279    2014-02-03   0.00000
9   252957  0.00    7.187185    2014-02-03   0.00000
```

Where the hours and minutes have been removed from the Period column. Does anyone know why this happens, or how to prevent it?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: This is probably OS specific in some way, the following command yields the correct result for me (R 3.1.1 on Mac OS X): `as.POSIXct(c('2014-02-03 00:00:00.000', '2014-02-03 01:00:00.000', '2014-02-03 02:00:00.000'))`.

Comment: I also get the correct result, R 3.1.1, windows 7.

Comment: I've actually found that there is exactly one date making trouble. 2014-03-31 03:00:00. For some unknown reason, when I remove that particular date, the conversion works. So I think you guys are correct, it should work, but perhaps there is something wrong with my data. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does anyone else get the following error: `a = strptime("2014-03-31 03:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`. `as.POSIXct(a)`. With the result being NA?

Comment: Are you by chance in Turkey? http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2014a.html Please state your time zone.

Comment: I'm in Cyprus. Why would that affect that one specific data point?

Comment: Follow the link in my comment.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, bit slow on the uptake. Ah! Well, time to rerun all that code then I guess haha! Thanks Roland!

Comment: General advice: Always specify time zones explicitly when creating POSIXt objects (by using the `tz` parameter).

Answer (score 4):

The other answers hint at the problem but don't really address it. `as.POSIXct(...)` has bizarre behaviour when a character vector is passed with an invalid time: rather than returning NA for those elements with invalid time, `as.POSIXct(...)` **removes the time part for all elements**.

You can "fix" this by explicitly providing the format specification, even though you are using the default spec (see last line below).

```
x <- sprintf('%02d:00:00', 20:25)          # 25:00:00 is not a valid time spec.
y <- sprintf('%s %s', '2018-01-01',x)      # last element has invalid time
as.POSIXct(head(y,-1))                     # works fine
## [1] "2018-01-01 20:00:00 HST" "2018-01-01 21:00:00 HST" "2018-01-01 22:00:00 HST" "2018-01-01 23:00:00 HST" "2018-01-02 00:00:00 HST"
as.POSIXct(y)                              # fails miserably
## [1] "2018-01-01 HST" "2018-01-01 HST" "2018-01-01 HST" "2018-01-01 HST" "2018-01-01 HST" "2018-01-01 HST"
as.POSIXct(y, tz='UTC')                    # tz does not fix this...
## [1] "2018-01-01 UTC" "2018-01-01 UTC" "2018-01-01 UTC" "2018-01-01 UTC" "2018-01-01 UTC" "2018-01-01 UTC"
as.POSIXct(y, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # but this does...
## [1] "2018-01-01 20:00:00 HST" "2018-01-01 21:00:00 HST" "2018-01-01 22:00:00 HST" "2018-01-01 23:00:00 HST" "2018-01-02 00:00:00 HST" NA
```

Running R 3.4.0 on Win 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `strptime`:

```
char_data = c('2014-02-03 00:00:00.000', '2014-02-03 01:00:00.000', '2014-02-03 02:00:00.000')
strptime(char_data, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
[1] "2014-02-03 00:00:00 CET" "2014-02-03 01:00:00 CET"
[3] "2014-02-03 02:00:00 CET"
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct` uses `strptime` to parse the datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

"2014-03-31 03:00:00" is not a valid datetime, where you live, as "2014-03-31 02:59:59" was immediately followed by "2014-03-31 04:00:00" due to switching to daylight saving time.